# Autofac dependency resolver passes the same value for parameters when resolving the service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, dependency-resolver

I am using Autofac for IoC in ASP .Net MVC 4 app.

I am not able to figure out why the dependency resolver is passing the same value for different parameters when resolving a dependency.

Here is how I am registering:

```
private void RegisterDependencyResolver()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    builder.Register(x => new AESCryptographyService()).As<ICryptographyService>();
    builder.RegisterType<AppContext>().As<IContext>();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

---

Here is how I am resolving `IContext`:

```
var factory = _dependencyResolver.GetService<Func<string, string, string, IContext>>();
IContext context = factory(contextToken, hostUrl, request.Url.Authority);
```

---

Here is my `AppContext`:

```
internal class AppContext : IContext
{
    public AppContext(string contextToken, string hostUrl, string appUrl)
    {
        AppUrl = appUrl;
        HostUrl = hostUrl;
        ContextToken = contextToken;
    }

    public string AppUrl { get; private set; }

    public string ContextToken { get; private set; }

    public string HostUrl { get; private set; }
}
```

---

Please have a look at this screenshot. Even though `contextToken`, `hostUrl`, and `request.Url.Authority` have different values, in the constructor of `AppContext` all the values are set to the value of `contextToken`.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

I had to replace this:

```
var factory = _dependencyResolver.GetService<Func<string, string, string, IContext>>();
IContext context = factory(contextToken, hostUrl, request.Url.Authority);
```

with this:

```
var context =
    _dependencyResolver.RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<IContext>(
        new NamedParameter("contextToken", contextToken), 
        new NamedParameter("hostUrl", hostUrl),
        new NamedParameter("appUrl", request.Url.Authority));
```